# Remove the first second objects in Corona Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I wanna create objects forever, after the 6th object was created, i wanna remove the first created one.  and then when the 7th was created, i wanna remove the second object. the loops goes like this.

```
j=0

    local  tekrarla = function () 

    local tekerdusur= {}

        j = j+1

    print (j)
    tekerdusur[j]  = display.newSprite( tekeranim, { name="tekergiris2", start=1, count=2, time=800 } )
    tekerdusur[j] .x = math.random (display.contentCenterX -400,display.contentCenterX+200) 
    tekerdusur[j] .y =  math.random (display.contentCenterY -300,display.contentCenterY +100) 
    tekerdusur[j] .bodyType = "dynamic"
    tekerdusur[j] .isBullet = true
    tekerdusur[j] :play()



   physics.addBody( tekerdusur[j] , { density=0.9, friction=0.5, bounce=0.6, radius=38 } )


if (j > 5) then
tekerdusur[j-5]:removeSelf()
tekerdusur [j-5]= nil

end
end

timer.performWithDelay(1000,tekrarla,-1)
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list for previous sprites. Add new ones to the end. If the list is has 5 entries, remove the oldest (the first) before adding another.

```
    local tekerdusur = {}

    local function tekrarla()
        local new = display.newSprite( tekeranim, { name="tekergiris2", start=1, count=2, time=800 } )
        new.x = math.random (display.contentCenterX - 400, display.contentCenterX + 200) 
        new.y = math.random (display.contentCenterY - 300, display.contentCenterY + 100) 
        new.bodyType = "dynamic"
        new.isBullet = true
        new:play()

        physics.addBody( new, { density=0.9, friction=0.5, bounce=0.6, radius=38 } )

        if #tekerdusur == 5 then
            tekerdusur[1]:removeSelf()
            table.remove(tekerdusur, 1)
        end
        table.insert(tekerdusur, new)
    end

    timer.performWithDelay(1000, tekrarla, -1)
```